# IE doesn't show a picture

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a website using Twitter Bootstrap and all browsers except for IE show my logo above the div with "brand" class. Its format is PNG.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container text-center">
  <img class="img-responsive brand-img" src="img/logo.png" alt="">
  <div class="brand">MG STAV</div>    
  <div class="address-bar"> stavební, spol. s.r.o.</div>
</div
```

**CSS**

```
.brand-img{
  display: inline; 
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;  

}
```

I need to make it work even with IE but I can't come with a solution.

Comment: Please provide live code example and tell which IE version you're using.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to provide live code example of the website which use Twitter Bootstrap. I am using ver. 11. @Nuno Arruda

Comment: Can you take a screen shot of what it is doing?

Comment: Oh try saying display: inline-block

Comment: Let me write up an answer for you to choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that the ".brand-image" div is given "display:inline".  Without seeing the actual live code it is hard to say but I think IE is rendering the image but giving the div it is in a hieght of 0px.

Try to change your css to inline-block.  This will keep the image position in line with the other "non block" level elements and let it still keep it's natural height.

CSS:

```
.brand-img{
   display: inline-block; 
   text-align: center;
   margin-top: 20px;
   margin-bottom: 10px; 
}
```

Comment: Working, just edit your CSS, it's not corrected in it